# Selecting pairs while filtering one of the columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we've got a list of Products along with Cities in which they are sold:

```
Product  City
-------------
1        2
1        3
1        4
2        4
```

Each City belongs to a State, and the State to a Country. State and Countries have nested, numbered IDs representing their relationship:

```
City   State
------------
2      1.2
3      1.3
4      2.1
```

```
State  Country
-----------
1.2      1
1.3      1
2.1      2
```

Let `(X, Y)` be the pair of Cities X and Y. `(X, Y)` and `(Y, X)` are the same for my purposes, and one of them must be removed

First, I want to count the number of products that are available in each pair:

```sql
SELECT t1.state, t2.state, COUNT(DISTINCT product.id) FROM
 (SELECT product_city.*, city.state as state from product_city
   INNER JOIN product ON product_city.product = product.id
   INNER JOIN city ON product_city.city = city.id
 ) t1
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT product_city.*, city.state as state from product_city
   INNER JOIN product ON product_city.product = product.id
   INNER JOIN city ON product_city.city = city.id
 ) t2
 ON t1.product = t2.product
 WHERE t1.state < t2.state
 ORDER t1.state ASC
 GROUP BY t1.state, t2.state
```

Suppose now that I only want to count those products with presence in State 2.1. I can apply filter to only `t1`,

```sql
(SELECT product_city.*, city.state as state from product_city
   INNER JOIN product ON product_city.product = product.id
   INNER JOIN city ON product_city.city = city.id
   WHERE city.state = '2.1'
 ) t1
```

but in that way I lose all the pairs because `t1.state` is always greater than the rest. If I change the check to `!=`, I get instead duplicated pairs because `(1.2, 1.3)` and `(1.3, 1.2)` are both counted.

How can I fix this? The expected response should be these two rows:

```
t1.state  t2.state  count
-------------------------
2.1       1.2       1
2.1       1.3       1
```

Comment: FTR, this is not a duplicate of e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161901  because I want to filter the list as well.

Comment: Kindly post your expected data for the problem statements and given sample data.

Comment: Also, how do you define pair of states

Answer (score 0):

You should CROSS JOIN the Product_City table to itself. That way you have every record in the table joined to every other record in the table. Meaning you'll have each product/city combo matched with each other combo

```
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM product_city p -- parent or target
    CROSS JOIN product_city c -- child or match
) product_city
```

Then you can join each side (the parent and the child) to the respective other tables to get all of the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Start with matching products to states:

```
select p.*, c.state
from products p join
     cities c
     on p.city = c.city;
```

Then, do a self join on this:

```
with ps as (
      select p.*, c.state
      from products p join
           cities c
           on p.city = c.city
     )
select ps.state, ps2.state, count(*)
from ps join
     ps ps2
     on ps2.product = ps.product and ps2.state < ps.state
group by ps.state, ps2.state
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want all states, even those with zero products, you can generate the state pairs using a `cross join` and then `left join` in the values that match:

```
with ps as (
      select p.*, c.state
      from products p join
           cities c
           on p.city = c.city
     ),
     ss as (
      select s.state, s2.state as state2
      from states s join
           states s2
           on s.state < s2.state
     )
select ss.state, ss.state2, count(ps2.product)
from ss left join
     ps
     on ps.state = ss.state left join
     ps ps2
     on ps2.state = ss.state2 and
        ps2.product = ps.product 
group by ss.state, ss.state2
order by count(ps2.product) desc;
```

Comment: It's perfect! However, I need it to filter pairs by State, so it's the same as my original solution.